# How do I use jquery to select a sibling of the parent element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to use jquery to specifically select a sibling a parent element that has the same . the code is like this:

HTML

```
    <div class="cool-check-list">
        <ul>
        <li>
            <label>
                <span class="icon"></span> <!-- trying to select this -->
                Awesome Label Name
            </label>

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <span class="icon"></span> <!-- clicking this toggles the class of the above icon class -->
                        Awesome Label Name 2
                    </label>    
                </li>                        
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
   </div>
```

JQUERY

```
    $('.icon', '.cool-check-list').click( function(e){

    $(this).parent('li label .icon').toggleClass('icon-alternate');

    });
```

Comment: every time the last icon is clicked, i want to toggle the first icon to change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you've already gotten a reference to the clicked span, you could do this:

```
$(this).closest("ul").siblings().find(".icon")
```

Where `this` is the `span` you clicked.  `closest` gets the nearest ancestor that matches the selector.

Answer (score 0):

You should tell us more precisely what you wanted to select and what you tried.

Anyway, you can use the parents() function of jquery, for instance :

```
$(".icon").parents("li")
```

will select **every** node li '*before*' the class icon in the DOM.

Btw, take care of the difference between [parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) and [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) - quoting the jquery documentation:

> The .parents() and .parent() methods
>   are similar, except that the latter
>   only travels a single level up the DOM
>   tree.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my original post above. something is not working

Comment: Thank you everyone for all your help!

Comment: you're welcome. if kingiv's answer fits for what you asked, do not forget to accept his answer !