# jQuery: how to find sibling from parent

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors, parent

If i have sth. like this

```
<div><input rel="first" type="radio" name="x" value="1"></div>
 …
<div><input type="radio" name="x" value="2" disabled></div>
 …
<div><input type="radio" name="x" value="3" disabled></div>
 …
<div><input type="radio" name="x" value="4"></div>
```

i want to find the next enabled radiobutton after rel="first" one.
As i had no divs wrapped, there was a simple way to find

```
$('input[rel="first"]').nextAll('input:radio').not(':disabled');
```

But i cant get them, now as i had to wrap inputs with a div.

```
$('input[rel="first"]').parent().nextAll('input:radio').not(':disabled');
```

not working either. Clearly parent() is searching next Element on the level of div. But how to get inside following divs? I have tried this

```
$('input[rel="first"]').parent().nextAll('div ~ input:radio').not(':disabled');
```

but it is also not working

Comment: Will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455436/how-do-i-use-jquery-to-select-a-sibling-of-the-parent-element

Comment: Try `.nextAll('div input:radio')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('input[rel="first"]')
  .parent() //it's parent div
  .nextAll('div') //finds nextAll div
  .children('input:radio') //inside div find input with radio type
  .not(':disabled'); //ensures not disabled
```

Comment: While that approach may arrive at the required result, it's seriously slow compared to a [*for loop*](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-pojs-20140714) using plain javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$('div:has(:radio[rel="first"])')
    .nextAll('div:has(:radio:not(:disabled))')
      .find(':radio')
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/69pFt/1/)

Comment: @too many edits in just one minute and you ask "care to comment"? :) any way it's not the way to do it.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan oh.. i just missed the .parent() at the first time.. i agree that was a mistake, and after that i just edited the post to make the answer better...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan sure.. i will become really happy while some other having a closer look at my code.. :) :D

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan `.nextAll('div').find(':radio:not(:disabled)')` This would do searching inside unnecessary divs right..? The div elements which don't have a radio button in enabled state..

Comment: know what? +1 from me :D

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan So nice of you.. Thanks for the encouragement..!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

```
$('input[rel="first"]').parent().nextAll('div').has('input:not(:disabled)').first()
```